# Transfer files to azure vm using ip address

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need to create a release definition in VSTS in which one task will be to copy jar files to azure vms using their ip address. These ip addresses will be stored in some variable of release definition. We are able to do it using ssh file copy task but we are creating ssh endpoint for that where we specify the address as hard coded value but we need to use variable there instead of hard coded value.
Is their any way to do it using batch script or powershell script. We need to move jar files to ubuntu VM on Azure.

Comment: IP address are generated when azure template deploys a VM on azure. We have that variable in release definition. And we need to move files to that VM using the IP address

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this blog: [Copy files to an Azure VM through PSRemoting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2016/04/04/copy-files-to-an-azure-vm-through-psremoting/)

Create credential with this code:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "PlainTextPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
```

On other hand, there is [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy)

Comment: I need to copy files to ubuntu VM. I tries this method but i am getting error that Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ToSession'

Comment: It requires PowerShell 5.0.

Comment: How about Azure File Copy task?

Comment: I have tried Azure file copy task but i am getting error in Destination Folder path. I have to copy files to ubuntu vm. What should be this setting value. Please give me a sample value

Comment: $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "Welcome#Infosys" -AsPlainText -Force

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("vatan", $secpasswd)

$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName HAProxyConsumer-dev -Port 5986 -Credential $cred

Copy-Item -Path %cd%\mqtt-consumer\target\mqtt-consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Destination \home\vatan -ToSession $sess

Comment: What're errors? Regarding Azure file copy task, add system.debug variable and set to true, then start release and post the detail log here.